Second order partial implicit derivatives
I have some function $F(x, y, z) = 0$, and wish to find the second order cross derivative
$\frac{d^2z}{dxdy}$.
I've easily been able to get the second order derivatives $\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}$ and $\frac{d^2z}{dy^2}$ through implicit differentiation:
we have that
$$\frac{dz}{dx}= \frac{-F_x}{F_z},$$
and therefore
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dz}{dx})&= \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{-F_x}{F_z})\\
&= -(\frac{\frac{d}{dx}F_x}{F_z} - \frac{F_x}{F_z^2}\frac{d}{dx}F_z)\\
& = -\frac{F_{xx} + F_{xz}\frac{dz}{dx}}{Fz} +\frac{F_x(F_{zx} + F_{zz}\frac{dz}{dx})}{F_z^2}.
\end{align}
I tried to do the same thing with the cross derivative:
$$\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{F_x}{F_z}$$
and
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dy}(\frac{dz}{dx})&= \frac{d}{dy}(\frac{F_x}{F_z})\\
&= \frac{\frac{d}{dy}F_x}{F_z} - \frac{F_x}{F_z^2}\frac{d}{dy}F_z\\
&= \frac{F_{xy} + F_{xz}\frac{dz}{dy}}{Fz} -\frac{F_x(F_{zy} + F_{zz}\frac{dz}{dy})}{F_z^2}.
\end{align}
Looking at this, is doesn't seem like it could be correct as $\frac{d^2z}{dxdy}$ is not symetric to $\frac{d^2z}{dydx}$. Indeed, when I check again finite differences, there are significant discrepancies. What am I doing incorrectly?
With some experimentation again the calculated finite differences, I get that the following is epsilon-close, although I can't seem to back out the correct derivation from there:
$$\frac{F_{xy} + F_{xz}\frac{dz}{dy}}{Fz} -\frac{F_x(F_{zy} + F_{zz}\frac{dz}{dy})}{F_z^2} + \frac{F_y(F_{zx} + F_{zz}\frac{dz}{dx})}{F_z^2}$$

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2135549/implicit-function-theorem-exercise-with-higher-derivatives for the correct formulas.

Thanks, I searched around quite a bit but couldn't find this.

Turns out the derivative here was correct, there was an issue w/ my finite differences check of it.

As regards the cross-derivative, you missed a minus sign at the first step:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)&= \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\color{blue}{-}\frac{F_x}{F_z}\right)=
-\frac{1}{F_z}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}F_x+\frac{F_x}{F_z^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}F_z\\
&=-\frac{F_{xy}+F_{xz}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}}{F_z}+\frac{F_x(F_{zy}+F_{zz}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y})}{F_z^2}\\
&=-\frac{F_{xy}+F_{xz}(-F_y/F_z)}{F_z}+\frac{F_x(F_{zy}+F_{zz}(-F_y/F_z))}{F_z^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{F_z^3}\left(F_{xz}F_y F_z+F_{zy}F_x F_z-F_{xy}F_z^2 -F_{zz}F_x F_y\right).
\end{align}
If $F$ is $C^2$ then the final formula does not change after swapping $x$ and $y$. Compare the result with the formula at the link given by Hans Lundmark above.
